# is there a way to convert a lead to an account with a particular recordtype programatically

Tags: apex, lead-conversion

I am programmatically convert a lead into Accounts and contacts. Is there a way we can convert a lead to an account of particular recordtype?

I cant seem to find anything on this on the docs. I do feel there is no documented way of doing this. Any workarounds which could be used?

Thanks

Comment: I know standard conversion process in UI takes the default Account record type of the running user's profile. Have a workflow update the record type of your newly created Account?

Comment: I guess this would be the way to go. Though i will wait for a few more responses. If you can write it up as an answer i can accept it as answer

Answer (score 0):

Standard conversion process in UI takes the default Account record type of the running user's profile. You can have a **workflow update the record type** of your newly created Account.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve it only by Apex only. You may write trigger to control the conversion when someone convert lead from UI.

This would help:

```
        Database.LeadConvert lc = new database.LeadConvert();
        lc.setLeadId(leadId);
        lc.setAccountId(accountId_of_a_RecordType)
        LeadStatus convertStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];
        lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);
        Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
```

Comment: This would convert to an existing account. If there is no account then i want to create one of particular recordtype

Comment: You can't,  RecordType doesn't support DML @Prady

Comment: I was almost sure we cant do it programmatically. As @Robin suggested looks like an workflow could be the way to go